# Memory usage by Compiz in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: nvidia, compiz

Having scanned the various sources to check out the issue with compiz memory leak, I have not found any solution to reduce it. It keeps growing and beyond a point, I have to restart the PC.

My config: AMD FX 4100 Quad core, 4 GB RAM, 64 GB SSD, Ubuntu 14.04, 64 bit, fully patched
Display card - GE FORCE 8400 GS - connected two monitors

[image: Compiz memory usafe - ubuntu 14-04 with GEFORCE 8400GS display card]

Any help is appreciated. This card works fine in Ubuntu 12.04 with compiz memory utilization hovering around 65 MB. There is no default display on the motherboard and I have to use this external display card.

Thanks for your help !